# Redirect to a page according to selected option from radio button through 'onclick' , without 'submit' the form in php

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is the code which is not working according to my requirement

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){

if(document.form.choice.value='pc'){

window.open('pc.php','_self');

return true;

}

else if(document.form.choice.value='ps2'){

window.open('ps2.php','_self');

return true;

}

else if(document.form.choice.value='ps3'){

window.open('ps3.php','_self');

return true;

}

else if(document.form.choice.value='psp'){

window.open('psp.php','_self');

return true;

}

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

Games<br /><br />

<form name="form">ALL &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" onClick="test()" name="choice" value="pc">PC &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" onClick="test()" name="choice" value="ps2">PS2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" onClick="test()" name="choice" value="ps3">PS3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" onClick="test()" name="choice" value="psp">PSP &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>

</body>
```

Also i want to know that how to display the field automatically just by selecting the selected field in Drop down list without 'submit'

```
<select name="genre">
        <option value="">--Select Genre and Click Go--</option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="Action / Mission">Action / Mission</option>
        <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
        <option value="Kids">Kids</option>
        <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
        <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

**EDITED:**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function idForm(){
   var selectvalue = $('input[name=choice]:checked', '#idForm').val();


if(selectvalue == "pc"){
window.open('http://www.google.com','_self');
return true;
}
else if(selectvalue == "ps2"){
window.open('http://www.google.com','_self');
return true;
}else if(selectvalue == 'ps3'){
window.open('http://www.google.com','_self');
return true;
}else if(selectvalue == 'psp'){
window.open('http://www.google.com','_self');
return true;
}
return false;
};


</script>
</head>
<body>
Games<br /><br />
<form id="idForm">ALL &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" onclick="idForm()"  name="choice" value="pc"/>PC &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio"  onclick="idForm()" name="choice" value="ps2"/>PS2 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio"  onclick="idForm()" name="choice" value="ps3"/>PS3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio"  onclick="idForm()" name="choice" value="psp"/>PSP &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
</body>
```

**Jsfiddle**
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/h1m8wg0t/)

Comment: not working..only one page is opening 'pc.php' no matter which ever button is selected.(i used the pages - pc.php, psp.php etc. instead of google.com) I want to dispaly different pages for different selections.

Comment: only one thing is troubling me..When i m clicking in any one of the button checked (blue mark inside the button) removes automatically, (no doubt that page is opening but blue mark removes), Plz resolve this.

Comment: I do not know do you mean, but can something like this (whith loading gif) http://jsfiddle.net/h1m8wg0t/1/

Comment: Sorry, but i tried & the code is working only 50%, (for opening the different pages, i have to press back button in browser each time, then only after this process i m able to open other pages, otherwise it hangs & shows the contents of one page only..I have made some changes & posting the new question, it will be help full to me if you resolve this new code.

Comment: I posted a question with a new code. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831147/automatically-redirect-the-pages-through-radio-button-drop-down-list-through  Please go through it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Perlica . Your code worked 100% for what i was searching. My mistake was i was not using ajax. After using that all went fine. Thnx a lot once again.

Comment: As you can see my code in question, there are two choice. First (which is solved by you), user have to select the Platform (PC, PS2, etc.). but second thing is when PC or PS2 page opens user have to select the "genre" (racing, arcade, etc) of the game also through Drop Down list, by the same procedure, i.e, just select the genre the display is here (no need to use submit). And by default full list is display.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the option by adding `onchange` event in the `<select>` tag.

```
<select name="genre" onchange="selectOption()">
            <option value="">--Select Genre and Click Go--</option>
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Action / Mission">Action / Mission</option>
            <option value="Arcade">Arcade</option>
            <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
            <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
            <option value="Kids">Kids</option>
            <option value="Strategy">Strategy</option>
            <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
          </select>
```

In your script add this

```
function selectOption(){
//each option value
var option=document.form.genre.value;
alert(option);


}
```

For redirecting you can use `window.location` in your `test()` method
use this `window.location=yourpage.php` instead of this `window.open('pc.php','_self')`

Comment: in php my code is --- please tell me where to put the option in.... if(@$_POST['genre']=="")
{
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes'");
}
else if(isset($_POST['genre']))
{
if($_POST['genre']=="All")
{
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes'");
}
else if($_POST['genre']=="Strategy")
{
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Strategy'");
}
else if($_POST['genre']=="Action / Mission")
{
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games where pc='yes' and genre='Action / Mission'");
}

Comment: i tried but it does not redirect automatically to selected 'genre'. Any Solution.?

Comment: You want to redirect to page accoring to the option in th dropdown menu?

Comment: Add  `window.location='yourpage.php'` in `selectOption()` method.

Comment: I posted a question with a new code. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831147/automatically-redirect-the-pages-through-radio-button-drop-down-list-through   Please go through it.